# [Vue warn]: Injection "select" not found (element-ui)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

2I am importing element-ui plugin in my custom vue.
It is working fine in stand alone vue app but after creating build.js with webpack and using it in my php app it is showing me

> [Vue warn]: Injection "select" not found
>
> (found in )

error in console and select dropdown is not working in that.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the same issue, the warning appears if you forget to wrap `el-option` elements in an `el-select` element